# Awk script to loop and perform mathematical operations

Tags: awk

I have bash and awk script that I use to extract data from the text file.
However it is too slow with large datasets and doesn't work perfectly. I believe that it is possible to write all my bash loop in one awk command and I ask somebody to help me with this.

```
cat dummy_list 
    AAA
    AAAA
    AAAAA

cat dummy_table
    13   19   AAA   69   96   "ID-999"   34
    23   42   AAA   12   19   "ID-999"   64
    53   79   AAA   43   58   "ID-482"   36
    13   43   AAA   12   15   "ID-492"   75
    23   90   AAA   45   87   "ID-492"   34
    12   41   AAAA   76   79   "ID-923"   23
    19   58   AAAA   15   87   "ID-923"   75
    10   40   AAAA   18   82   "ID-482"   23
    11   18   AAAA   18   82   "ID-482"   52
    15   19   AAAA   18   82   "ID-482"   62
    59   69   AAAA   10   18   "ID-482"   83
    78   89   AAAA   32   41   "ID-983"   24
    23   53   AAAAA  78   99   "ID-916"   82
```

What I want from this table:

1. For every dummy_list item (`AAA` or `AAAA` or `AAAAA`) extract how many different times ID range was mentioned ( by this I mean unique columns 4+5+6 (like `69   96   "ID-999"`)). There are duplicate ID's (like `18   82   "ID-482"`) and I have to discard them.
   My script looks like this:

   ```
   while read a; do  
       awk -v VAR="$a" '($3==VAR) {print $4"\t"$5"\t"$6}' dummy_table |   
       sort -u |   
       cut -f 3 |  
       sort |   
       uniq -c |   
       awk '{print $1}' |   
       tr '\n' ' ' |   
      awk -v VAR="$a" '{print VAR"\t"$0}'   
   done < dummy_list

   AAA     1 2 2 
   AAAA    2 2 1 
   AAAAA   1
   ```

   It's the same as `AAA "ID-482" mentioned once; "ID-492" mentioned twice; "ID-999" mentioned twice`.

   This is the output I want.
2. For every dummy_list item get average number of how many times it gets mentioned with the same ID. For example `AAA` occurs twice with `"ID-999"`, one time with `"ID-482"` and two times with `"ID-492"` - so it's (2+1+2)/3=1.66

   My script looks like this:

   ```
   while read a ; do  
       ID_TIMES=$(awk -v VAR="$a" '($3==VAR) {print $6}' dummy_table | 
          sort -u | 
           wc -l) && 
       awk -v  VAR="$a" '($3==VAR) {print $6}' dummy_table | 
       sort | 
       uniq -c | 
       awk -v VAR="$ID_TIMES" '{sum+=$1} END {print sum/VAR}' 
   done < dummy_list

   AAA   1.666  
   AAAA  2.333
   AAAAA 1
   ```
3. For every dummy_list item extract ID range and calculate proportion between columns. 
   For example:
   `for AAA's ID-999:

       RANGE1=sum $5-$4(96-69) + $5-$4(19-12)

       RANGE2=sum $7(34+64)

       then RANGE2*100/RANGE1=288`
   For the output like this:

   ```
   AAA 288 240 242 
   ....
   AAAAA 390
   ```

   I wasn't able to write such script by myself as I got stuck with two variables $RANGE1 and $RANGE2.
   If it it possible it would be great to discard duplicate ranges like `18   82   "ID-482"` in this step as well.

I believe that all these there operations can be calculated with only one `awk` command and I feel desperate about my scripts.  I really hope that someone will help me in this operation.

Comment: Have you considered using a relational database?

Comment: This is why I need all this data extraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.

file a.awk:

```
BEGIN {

    # read list of items

    while ( ( getline < "dummy_list" ) > 0 )
    {
        items[$1] = 0    
    }
}

{
    # calculate ammountof uniqur ids

    key = $3 SUBSEP $6

    if ( ! ( key in ids ) && ( $3 in items ) )
    {
        unique_ids[$3] += 1 
    }


    # calculate ammount of duplication

    ids [$3,$6] += 1 


    # calculate range parameters 

    range1 [$3,$6] += $5 - $4
    range2 [$3,$6] += $7 
}

END {

    for ( item in items )
    {
        print "--- item = " item " ---\n"

        for ( key in ids )
        {
            split ( key, s, SUBSEP );

            if ( s[1] != item ) continue;    

            range = range2[key] * 100 / range1[key] 

            average[item] += float ( ids[key] ) / unique_ids[item];

            print "id = " s[2] "\tammount of dup = " ids[key] "  range = " int ( range )
        }    

        print "\naverage = " average[item] "\n"
    }
}
```

run:

`awk -f a.awk dummy_table`

output:

```
--- item = AAAA ---

id = "ID-983"   ammount of dup = 1  range = 266
id = "ID-923"   ammount of dup = 2  range = 130
id = "ID-482"   ammount of dup = 4  range = 110

average = 2.33333

--- item = AAAAA ---

id = "ID-916"   ammount of dup = 1  range = 390

average = 1

--- item = AAA ---

id = "ID-999"   ammount of dup = 2  range = 288
id = "ID-482"   ammount of dup = 1  range = 240
id = "ID-492"   ammount of dup = 2  range = 242

average = 1.66667
```

There is one moment - I can't understand how you got 225 
for "ID-482" and item AAA in question #3.

```
RANGE2 * 100 / RANGE1 = 36 * 100 / ( 58 - 43 ) = 240.
```

Are you sure, that your example on question #3 is correct?

Comment: My mistake - had to calculate percents manually, I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

Only a partial answer but here is a one-liner solution for your first problem:

```
  awk -F'   ' '{group[$3]++;ind[$6]++};{count[$3][$6]+=1}; END{for (i in group){for (j in ind) if(count[i][j] > 0) print i, j, count[i][j]}}' dummy_variable.txt
```

Output:

```
AAA "ID-482" 1  
AAA "ID-999" 2  
AAA "ID-492" 2    
AAAA "ID-923" 2  
AAAA "ID-482" 4  
AAAA "ID-983" 1  
AAAAA "ID-916" 1
```

It is then fairly trivil to use this output to calculate the answer to your second question.

Comment: `while read a ; do NUMBER=$(grep -w $a OUTPUT | awk '{print $2}' | sort -u | wc -l) && awk -v ID="$a" -v NUMBER="$NUMBER" '($1==ID) {sum+=$3} END {print sum/NUMBER}' OUTPUT ; done < dummy_list`  
I have problem writing everything in one awk command and joining this with previous step.